# How to create a new AssemblyItem in Netsuite PHP toolkit?

Tags: php, netsuite

I am trying to send the order info from Woocommerce into Netsuite as a sale order, when creating a new order. In order to create a new sale order by PHP toolkit, it is necessary for me to create Assembly Items first.

Is there a way to create a new Item using PHP-toolkit?

Here is a PHP code snippet for creating a new Item myself.

```html
$service = new NetSuiteService();

$ai = new AssemblyItem();

// Rustica Group Item Form - 20
$ai->customForm = new RecordRef();
$ai->customForm->internalId = 20;

$ai->memberList = new ItemMemberList();

$item_member = array();
$itemMember = new ItemMember();
$itemMember->internalId = 186625;
$item_member[] = $itemMember;

$ai->memberList->itemMember = $item_member;

$ai->itemId = 'Hardware' . $data['itemId'];
$ai->displayName = $data['displayName'];
$ai->vendorName = '';
$ai->cost = $data['price'];
$ai->isTaxable = $data['taxable'];
$ai->description = $data['description'];

$request = new AddRequest();
$request->record = $ai;

$addResponse = $service->add($request);
print_r($addResponse);

if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    return "ADD ERROR";
} else {
    return $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
}
```

Comment: You see, You are putting this kind of stuff: `for ($i = 0;$i < 1;$i ++) {` instead cleaning it up and making easier for people who will try to help You.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Will fix that. :)

Comment: I don't know the answer, haven't been using PHP toolkit, but for god's sake, WHY: 
`$item_member = array();
$itemMember = new ItemMember();`

Answer (score 1):

There is no internalid field for ItemMember.  Look at the [schema](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/other/itemmember.html?mode=package)

Should look like this...

```
$itemMember = new ItemMember();
$itemMember->item = new RecordRef();
$itemMember->item->internalId = 186625;
```

You're missing taxSchedule too..not sure if you are confusing that with isTaxable

```
$ai->taxSchedule = new RecordRef();
$ai->taxSchedule->internalId = 1; //whatever tax schedule you're using
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. if I don't know the internal id of the item that I tried to add, how can I add this product to the netsuite.

Comment: Assembly item requires you to include an item when creating.  If you don't know the internal id, do you know the item name/number?  If so, perform a search for that item by name which returns the internalid.

Answer (score 0):

You should pre-store the item of the product before saving the product that you want to send from Woocommerce into Netsuite.
If you store the item on netsuite, they will return the internal_id of the item.
Then, you can save the item with internal id that they return.